# Замена текста на изображение в c#

Tags: c#, изображения, ms-word

Как можно заменить текст на изображение? Пытаюсь через буфер обмена-простое место вместо текста.

```
Clipboard.SetImage(Image.FromFile("E:\\Dropbox\\Фонд\\1310\\опрос\\1210\\Statistick_program\\Statistick_program\\bin\\Debug\\dig1.bmp"));
    // copy the image to the clipboard

  //  Clipboard.SetImage("^E:\\Dropbox\\Фонд\\1310\\опрос\\1210\\Statistick_program\\Statistick_program\\bin\\Debug\\dig1.bmp");

    app.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText: "<dig1>", ReplaceWith: Clipboard.GetImage());

    object SaveASFile = (object)Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Temp57.doc";
    doc.SaveAs(SaveASFile, missing, missing, missing, missing);
    doc.Close(false, missing, missing);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вот и ответ:

```
   var app = new Application();
        try {
            //This code creates a document based on the specified template.
            var doc = app.Documents.Add(
                Path.GetFullPath(@"Docs\foo.dotx"),
                Visible: false);

            doc.Activate();

            //for each keyword you want to replace.
            //************************************************
            var keyword = "angus-young";
            Console.WriteLine("Replacing keyword: {0} ...",keyword);
            var sel = app.Selection;                
            sel.Find.Text = string.Format("[{0}]", keyword);                
            sel.Find.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceNone);
            sel.Range.Select();                

            //This code inserts the image
            var imgPath = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(@"Img\{0}.jpg", keyword));
            sel.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
                FileName: imgPath,
                LinkToFile: false,
                SaveWithDocument: true);
            //************************************************

            //finally, save the doc.
            doc.SaveAs(Path.GetFullPath(@"Docs\foo.docx"));
            doc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally {                
            app.Quit();
            sys.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);                
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
```

Console.ReadLine();